# Java and AppStore receipt verification

Tags: java, ios, in-app-purchase

I am trying to verify a payment receipt on server side. 
I am getting a `{"status":21002, "exception":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"}` in return

Here is the code:

```
private final static String _sandboxUriStr = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";

public static void processPayment(final String receipt) throws SystemException
{
    final BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    final String receiptData = encoder.encode(receipt.getBytes());


    final String jsonData = "{\"receipt-data\" : \"" + receiptData + "\"}";

    System.out.println(receipt);
    System.out.println(jsonData);

    try
    {
        final URL url = new URL(_sandboxUriStr);
        final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        final OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(jsonData);
        wr.flush();

        // Get the response
        final BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        wr.close();
        rd.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        throw new SystemException("Error when trying to send request to '%s', %s", _sandboxUriStr, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

My receipt looks like this:

```
{\n\t"signature" = "[exactly_1320_characters]";\n\t"purchase-info" =
"[exactly_868_characters]";\n\t"environment" = "Sandbox";\n\t"pod" =
"100";\n\t"signing-status" = "0";\n}
```

Receipt data with a BASE64 encoded receipt looks like this:

```
{"receipt-data" : "[Block_of_chars_76x40+44=3084_chars_total]"}
```

Does someone have an Idea, or sample code how can I get from receipt string to reply JSON, mentioned [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH104-SW1)?

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13717476/642706): `the JSON Object that you have created to send for verification is not in correct format`.

Answer (score 4):

21002 : The problem was at Base64 encoding inside Java. When I do the encoding inside IOS and use that as the request from server without any encoding in Java, then it worked.

```
switch (status) {
        case 21000:
            msg = "The App Store could not read the JSON object you provided";
            logger.info("\n  21000 : The App Store could not read the JSON object you provided. ");

        break;
    case 21002:
        msg = "The data in the receipt-data property was malformed.";
        logger.info("\n  21002 : The data in the receipt-data property was malformed..   ");
        break;
    case 21003:
        msg = "The data in the receipt-data property was malformed.";
        logger.info("\n  21003 : The receipt could not be authenticated. ");
        break;
    case 21004:
        msg = "TThe shared secret you provided does not match the shared secret on file for your account.";
        logger.info("\n  21004 : The shared secret you provided does not match the shared secret on file for your account. ");
        break;
    case 21005:
        msg = "The receipt server is not currently available.";
        logger.info("\n  21005 : The receipt server is not currently available. ");
        break;
    case 21006:
        msg = "This receipt is valid but the subscription has expired. When this status code is returned to your server, the receipt data is also decoded and returned as part of the response.";
        logger.info("\n  21006 : This receipt is valid but the subscription has expired. When this status code is returned to your server, the receipt data is also decoded and returned as part of the response. ");
        break;
    case 21007:
        msg = "This receipt is a sandbox receipt, but it was sent to the production service for verification.";
        logger.info("\n  21007 : This receipt is a sandbox receipt, but it was sent to the production service for verification. ");
        break;
    case 21008:
        msg = "This receipt is a production receipt, but it was sent to the sandbox service for verification.";
        logger.info("\n  21008 : This receipt is a production receipt, but it was sent to the sandbox service for verification. ");
        break;

    default:
        msg = "Active subscription.";
        logger.info("\n  0 : valid ....Active subscription. ");
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

JSONObject requestData = new JSONObject();
requestData.put("receipt-data", recept);
requestData.put("password", password);


HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt");
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(requestData.toString());
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
System.out.println(result.toString());
response.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that service but I've seen similar errors with other services when the content type or accepts headers where not set appropriately.

Try something like

```
 con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
 con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

(Or whatever they are expecting. I'm assuming json)

Comment: Thank you, tried to add these, didn't work. The same error: {"status":21002, "exception":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"}

Answer (score 0):

For everyone arriving here later, make sure to call toString() on your JSONObject. So in case you are using resTemplate, use:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("receipt-data", "your-receipt");

    // This will result in a response with status 21002 (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/status)
    HttpEntity<JSONObject> httpEntityRequest = new HttpEntity<>(jsonObject);

    // call toString() makes it work!
    HttpEntity<String> httpEntityRequest = new HttpEntity<>(jsonObject.toString());

    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(appleVerifyReceiptUrl, httpEntityRequest, String.class);
```