# Apple Receipt Verifier returns JsonException

Tags: c#, asp.net, ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

In my Purchase Verification Process a three Parties

1. iOS Client
2. ASP.NET Server (intermediary for verification)
3. Apple Server

JSON-RCP in the communication method between iOS Client & ASP.NET Server

The Verification Process is; Sending the Payment Receipt through web-service to the ASP.NET Server ( the server use [AppleReceiptVerifier](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AppleReceiptVerifier/) to Verify the Receipt)

I have 5 Product Identifiers for the payment 2 of them operate well and return the expected response but the other three return JsonException like this

```
{
    error =     {
        errors =         (
                        {
                message = "Found String where Object was expected.";
                name = JsonException;
            }
        );
        message = "Found String where Object was expected.";
        name = JSONRPCError;
    };
    id = "<null>";
}
```

and this

```
{
    error =     {
        errors =         (
                        {
                message = "Missing value.";
                name = JsonException;
            }
        );
        message = "Missing value.";
        name = JSONRPCError;
    };
    id = "<null>";
}
```

All the product identifiers are the same type they just vary in the price
and i don't know why is this problem ???

What to do ???

Comment: seems like the ios client does n't like the fomat of your json...may be ty some had coded json first with square brackets

Comment: i don't think this is the case because the same code with other identifiers works perfectly

Comment: Am I understanding correctly: This is the error, that your ASP.NET server throws when trying to parse some JSON it recieved from the iOS app? Can you insert or upload the actual JSON document you're trying to parse?

Comment: {"method":"sendReceipt","params":{"ReceiptData":"ewoJInNpZ25hdHVyZSIgPSAiQXJ.....","PersonID":"sam@am.com"},"id":"1"}
The points replace the remaining of the actual Receipt Data it's too long but this is the JSON-RPC

Comment: notice that this JSON can be parsed perfectly for other product identifier

Comment: Since its a 3 party environment can you check if it blows up in ios->asp.net or in asp.net->apple server.

Comment: ios->asp.net I'm sure with this

Answer (score 2):

After reading the specification of [json-rpc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC#Examples),
It seems that params is an array, try this:

```
{
  "method":"sendReceipt",
  "params" :[
    {
      "ReceiptData":"ewoJInNpZ25hdHVyZSIgPSAiQXJ....‌.",
      "PersonID":"sam@am.com"
    }
  ],
  "id":"1"
}
```

or this:

```
{
  "method":"sendReceipt",
  "params" :[
    "ewoJInNpZ25hdHVyZSIgPSAiQXJ....‌.",
    "sam@am.com"
  ],
  "id":"1"
}
```

jsonrpc version 2.0:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0", 
    "method": "sendReceipt", 
    "params": 
     {
      "ReceiptData":"ewoJInNpZ25hdHVyZSIgPSAiQXJ....‌.",
      "PersonID":"sam@am.com"
     }, 
     "id": 1
}
```

They should both work depending on your needs.

Comment: {"method":"sendReceipt","params":["ewoJInNpZ25hdHVyZSIgPSAiQX.....","mohand@amc.com"],"id":"1"}

|| I've used this JSON-RPC and it's not work 

|| errors =         (
                        {
                message = "Missing value.";
                name = JsonException;
            }
        );

Comment: what version of jsonrpc are you using?

Comment: version 2.0: `{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "sendReceipt", "params": {"ReceiptData":"ewoJInNpZ25hdHVyZSIgPSAiQXJ....‌​.","PersonID":"sam@am.com"}, "id": 1}`

Comment: how could i know what is the version i'm using ?

Comment: https://github.com/mladjan/JSONRPC-Tester/tree/master/JSONRPC%20Tester
this is the class i'm using to request and parse JSON-RPC

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are using the third party Library for verification when Apple provide environment to verify it.

Here you can directly post the JSON & get response with proper error code. Apple also well documented each error in their [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH104-SW3)

FYI use https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt to verify receipt in sandbox environment.

Refer [StoreKIt verification error: 21002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717148/storekit-verification-error-21002) for more info.