# Verifying In-App Purchase with AppStore using data from In-App Plugin for Xamarin

Tags: asp.net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, in-app-purchase, app-store

In my Xamarin Forms 5 app, I'm using the in-app purchase [plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin). I'm now trying to verify this purchase in my ASP.NET backend API by calling the [AppStore API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store).

When a purchase goes through, the response object I receive looks like below:

[image]

The [AppStore API documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/requestbody) indicates that the request body for the `POST` call I need to make should include the following properties:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out what I need to send as `receipt-data` which is supposed to be of type `byte`.

So far, I tried sending the `PurchaseToken` property I receive in the response object -- using the In-App Plugin -- see first image above. That failed. I then converted the `PurchaseToken` value to a byte array using the following conversion and that failed too.

```
var byteValue = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(purchaseTokenValue);
```

I keep getting `{ "status": 21002 }` from AppStore API which apparently means malformed according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717148/storekit-verification-error-21002-the-data-in-the-receipt-data-property-was-mal).

Has anyone called AppStore API for [purchase verification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store) using the data from the [In-App Billing plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin)? I'd appreciate some pointers here. Thanks!

UPDATE:

I also installed the beta version of the plugin (6.3.2 Beta). Even though the response object has changed, I still don't see any data about the receipt e.g. `receipt-data`.

[image]

Comment: there is a `ReceiptData` property in the plugin

Comment: I don't see `ReceiptData`. The first picture I posted in the question is all I see in the response object.

Comment: it appears to be in pre-release - https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin/commit/b281090948d87a8a236cd2524a6dd75005b4c16e

Comment: I installed the beta version of the plugin and I still don't see it -- see the UPDATE section in original post.

Comment: I have no idea.  I was just going by what I see in the source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution is as follows. First, I upgraded to the latest (pre-release) Beta version of the plugin. In my case that ended up being `6.3.2-beta`.

In the case of iOS, the receipt data does NOT come in the transaction object we get for the purchase. I'm providing the code including the purchase call and platform specific steps so that it's clear for everyone:

```
// First, make the purchase call and get transaction data
var purchase = await billing.PurchaseAsync(productId, ItemType.Subscription);

// We then handle platform specific steps
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
{
   // Must call AcknowledgePurchaseAsync else the purchase will be refunded
   await billing.AcknowledgePurchaseAsync(purchase.PurchaseToken);
}
else if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
{
   // Grab receipt data
   var receiptData = CrossInAppBilling.Current.ReceiptData;
}
```