# IOS Receipt validation IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, ios, app-store

I use similar code as its shown here in the question.
[Java and AppStore receipt verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432147/java-and-appstore-receipt-verification)

But I still end up getting

```
{"status":21002, "exception":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"}
```

Can it be a problem at Base64 encoding?. Do I have to convert the base64 encoded string into hex or something else?.

What i post is similar to following

```
{"receipt-data" : "eyJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiJBbjNJVER0VVNmZWNhaGMxR.....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was at Base64 encoding inside Java. When I do the encoding inside IOS and use that as the request from server without any encoding in Java, then it worked.

Comment: Seems odd that this would make a difference, no? Maybe there is a difference in the receipt you get from Apple and the way it's received by your backend?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and was receiving the java.lang.IllegalArgumentException from Apple when trying to validate a receipt on my server. The problem was that my base64 encoding logic was inserting lines breaks into the encoded string. Once I updated my code to ensure no new line breaks were being inserted into the encoded string, I was able to successfully verify my receipts against Apple's servers.