# Java app store receipt validation

Tags: java, in-app-purchase

I am trying to validate an Apple App Store receipt from a Java service. I can not get anything back other than an error 21002, "Receipt Data Property Was Malformed". I have read of others with the same problem, but, have not see a solution. I thought this would be fairly straight forward, but, have not been able to get around the error.  Here is my code:

**EDIT** By making the change marked // EDIT below, I now get an exception in the return from the verifyReceipt call, also makred //EDIT:

```
    String hexDataReceiptData = "<30821e3b 06092a86 4886f70d 010702a0 .... >";
    // EDIT
    hexDataReceiptData = hexDataReceiptData.replace(">", "").replace("<", "");
    final String base64EncodedReceiptData = Base64.encode(hexDataReceiptData.getBytes());
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try
    {
        jsonObject.put("receipt-data",base64EncodedReceiptData);
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    URL url = new URL("https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt");
    HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    //Send request
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(jsonObject.toString());
    wr.flush();

    //Get Response  
    BufferedReader rd = 
       new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder httpResponse = new StringBuilder(); 
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
    {
        httpResponse.append(line);
        httpResponse.append('\r');
    }
    wr.close();
    rd.close();
    // EDIT
    // {"status":21002, "exception":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"}
```

Comment: I am surprised I have only gotten 17 views on this. I can't be the only one doing IAP with Java. Can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted here: [Java and AppStore receipt verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432147/java-and-appstore-receipt-verification), do the base64 encoding in iOS and send to the server. But, why?